# MySQL: Is there a way to select a column and use it in "multiple ways"?

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I'm learning MySQL and I'm facing a problem that I cannot find an answer to. I have a database that includes columns: company and company_response. I have now queried the companies in a descending order so that the company that has closed most complaints with relief are on top. The problem is that I now have to count the ratio of instances of "Closed with relief". There are two other response options and I cannot find a way to make a **"ratio" column (closed with relief / all complaints closed)** so that I could display the ratio next to the relieve amount. Is there anyone that could be able to help me with this?

In practice, I don't know how to make an "all instances" and thus ratio column, as I have already used the where-clause to make my `Total relieves` column

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT company AS "Company name", count(company_response) AS "Total relieves"
FROM cfpb_complaints_2500
WHERE company_response = "Closed with relief"
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY count(company_response) DESC;
```

Comment: use a more standard name (without spaces). Use the query to retrieve the results in a consistent manner, not to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a conditional count:

```
SELECT company AS "Company name",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN company_response = 'Closed with relief' THEN 1 END) as "Total Relieves",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN company_response = 'Closed with relief' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) as "Ratio of Relieves"
FROM cfpb_complaints_2500
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Is there a way to alter this query so, that it would order by the company that has most relieves? I tried adding ORDER BY "Total Relieves", but it didn't work.

Comment: @coderfrombiz No problem, glad it helped - try using backticks instead of quotes around `Total Relieves` in your `ORDER BY`

Comment: I got it to work with ```ORDER BY `Total Relieves` DESC```. Thanks again!

Comment: @coderfrombiz Good deal :) Btw, that order by behavior with aliases is documented here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html, and the conditional count in my answer works because `ELSE` defaults to returning `NULL` which isn't counted.  You could also use `SUM(... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, it's just up to personal preference really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery that count all complaint from teh a company

> ```
> CREATE tABLE cfpb_complaints_2500 (company int,company_response varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> insert INTO cfpb_complaints_2500 VALUES (1,"Closed with relief")
> ,(1,"Closed with relief")
> ,(1,"Closed without relief")
> ,(1,"Closed without relief")
> ,(1,"Closed without relief")
> ,(1,"Closed without relief"),(2,"Closed with relief")
> ,(2,"Closed with relief")
> ,(2,"Closed without relief")
> ,(2,"Closed without relief")
> ```

> ```
> SELECT company AS "Company name"
> ,count(company_response) AS "Total relieves"
> , count(company_response)/ (SELECT count(*) FROM cfpb_complaints_2500 WHERE company = cf.company) AS "ratio" 
> FROM cfpb_complaints_2500 cf
> WHERE company_response = "Closed with relief"
> GROUP BY company
> ORDER BY ratio DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> Company name | Total relieves |  ratio
> -----------: | -------------: | -----:
>            2 |              2 | 0.5000
>            1 |              2 | 0.3333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=517c155f461b646e13e8d43053b587b4)*

Comment: thank you! For some reason, the ```ORDER BY``` -command doesn't work properly for me, but otherwise it works well

Comment: It did not show the highest ratio at top first. Must have been my mistake as it works now. I apologize for the inconvenience.